# Page title in stateless functional components

Tags: reactjs, jsx

How do you do this in stateless functional components? I tried this but it doesn't work:
`ComponentName.componentDidMount = () => document.title = "Who's Marco?"`
Where the ComponentName is something like this:

```
export const Life = ({sayHello="Ciao"}) => (

)
```

Comment: If you want to use React lifecycle methods (e.g. `componentDidMount`) then your component is no longer Stateless and thus is now Stateful.

Comment: oh that's a shame but thanks

Comment: I changed it to a class but `ComponentName.componentDidMount = () => document.title = "Who's Marco?"` still doesn't work...

Comment: You would need something like this: https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KkuSqHpVeJ2UVGOh6TX - This will render the document title as `Ciao!`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you set the document title in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46160461/how-do-you-set-the-document-title-in-react)

Answer (score 3):

With a functional component, you can use [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

For example,

```
useEffect(() => {
  document.title = "Who's Marco?"
}, []);
```

Adding the empty array in useEffect calls the function only once, just like a `componentDidMount` life cycle method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) to change the title in the render method, which should keep your component stateless. This does mean adding a dependency to your project though, and may be overkill for your needs.

```
const HelloWorld = ({name}) => (
  <div>
    {`Hi ${name}`}
    <Helmet>
        <title>Who's Marco?</title>
    <Helmet>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: I changed it to a class but `ComponentName.componentDidMount = () => document.title = "Who's Marco?"` still doesn't work...