# How do you set the document title in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I would like to set the document title (in the browser title bar) for my React application. I have tried using [react-document-title](https://github.com/gaearon/react-document-title) (seems out of date) and setting `document.title` in the `constructor` and `componentDidMount()` - none of these solutions work.

Comment: I confirm, react-document-title works great with react 16.5

Comment: If you just want to change the title you can edit title in index.html file which contain inside the public folder

Comment: @IshanFernando this is not a solution when you have multi-language support. We don't need a temporary page title from index.html flashing while a page is loading.

Answer (score 287, accepted):

For React 16.8+ you can use the [Effect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) in function components:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

function Example() {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = 'My Page Title';
  }, []);
}
```

To manage all valid head tags, including `<title>`, in declarative way, you can use [React Helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';

const TITLE = 'My Page Title';

class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent {
  render () {
    return (
      <>
        <Helmet>
          <title>{ TITLE }</title>
        </Helmet>
        ...
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: this will 'flash' the contents of the index.html in the first second, right?

Comment: This should definitely be the top answer. It's an excellent declarative way to manage the title and other meta attributes

Comment: Usage of helmet in React 16 has an issue https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/issues/548

Comment: Seems like overkill to set one single <title> tag.

Comment: @nxmohamad Yes, the "flash" issue can be resolved by removing the title tag altogether from the index.html file. Only downside being you have to make sure to give a title on every page or else it defaults to the domain name.

Comment: like @Reactgular said this is overkill. Generally it's not advisable to bring in dependencies to solve problems that can be easily solved with what's already available. Sure the API might be nicer than `document.title` but you've just introduced potentially more complexity for no palpable benefit by adding relying on a library for something like this.

Comment: @Reactgular agreed. I've updated the answer to point out that Helmet can be used to manage all head tags, not only title. And added an example of using Effect hook in React 16.8+

Comment: You may not need useEffect() if you are using functional components. `document.title = props.title` can be set and updated with a props change. It can even be set inside of render.

Comment: Is there no way to modify the template for static code like this? Have we really come to a point where static content needs to be scripted?

Answer (score 188):

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'


class Doc extends React.Component{
  componentDidMount(){
    document.title = "dfsdfsdfsd"
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <b> test </b>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Doc />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

This works for me.

Edit: If you're using webpack-dev-server set inline to true

Comment: This works but the document title is still "React App" while the page is loading - any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Change the content of the title tag in your index.html

Comment: Better to do it declaratively like in @quotesBro's answer

Comment: Is this way OK for SEO?

Comment: @AlexVestin Not a good idea if you need different titles for different views in your React application

Comment: Why can't I update the document title in other components if my index.js file sets the title to start?

Comment: From reactjs version 16.3 'componentWillMount' is not recommended instead use 'UNSAFE_componentWillMount' & this is also not advisable in strict mode

Comment: where do I put `inline:true`?

Answer (score 160):

For React 16.8, you can do this with a functional component using [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

For Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
   document.title = "new title"
}, []);
```

Having the second argument as an array calls useEffect only once, making it similar to `componentDidMount`.

Comment: How can this be tested with jest and enzyme?

Comment: +1. Note that if the title is *computed* in some way -- which it probably is, otherwise you would just set it in `<title>...</title>` and not touch it in your React component -- then the second argument should probably be `["new title"]` rather than `[]`, so that React knows to re-execute this hook if/when the computed title changes.

Comment: Until page loads it is React APP, then changes to "new title" very ugly.

Answer (score 55):

As others have mentioned, you can use `document.title = 'My new title'` and [React Helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) to update the page title.  Both of these solutions will still render the initial 'React App' title before scripts are loaded.

If you are using `create-react-app` the **initial** document title is set in the `<title>` tag `/public/index.html` file.

You can edit this directly or use a placeholder which will be filled from environmental variables:

`/.env`:

```
REACT_APP_SITE_TITLE='My Title!'
SOME_OTHER_VARS=...
```

If for some reason I wanted a different title in my development environment -

`/.env.development`:

```
REACT_APP_SITE_TITLE='**DEVELOPMENT** My TITLE! **DEVELOPMENT**'
SOME_OTHER_VARS=...
```

`/public/index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
         ...
         <title>%REACT_APP_SITE_TITLE%</title>
         ...
     </head>
     <body>
         ...
     </body>
</html>
```

This approach also means that I can read the site title environmental variable from my application using the global `process.env` object, which is nice:

```
console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_SITE_TITLE_URL);
// My Title!
```

See: [Adding Custom Environment Variables](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env)

Comment: Make sure to put the .env files at the same level of your package.json file. :)

Comment: I tried this but %REACT_APP_SITE_TITLE% is displayed as title.
I have kept .env in same level as package.json and using react-scripts 3.4.1

Comment: @YuvrajPatil This is only applied at build time. If you need to inject them at runtime, https://create-react-app.dev/docs/title-and-meta-tags#generating-dynamic-meta-tags-on-the-server

Comment: I believe this is the most reasonable solution unless you want to change the title within a component

Answer (score 50):

Since React 16.8. you can build a custom hook to do so (similar to the solution of @Shortchange):

```
export function useTitle(title) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const prevTitle = document.title
    document.title = title
    return () => {
      document.title = prevTitle
    }
  })
}
```

this can be used in any react component, e.g.:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  useTitle("New Title")
  return (
    <div>
     ...
    </div>
  )
}
```

It will update the title as soon as the component mounts and reverts it to the previous title when it unmounts.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this only works with Function components, and not Class components.

Comment: Best answer for modern React! The idea to reset the title is great.

Comment: Great hook, works great in function components.
as Alex already told us, it is not working in a class component, I just made a test to make sure.

Comment: Shouldn't this solution set the dependencies to [] so that its only ran on mount and unmount?

Comment: This is the best solution till now. Great stuff. Keep up

Answer (score 30):

```
import React from 'react';

function useTitle(title: string): void => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const prevTitle = document.title;
    document.title = title;

    return () => {
      document.title = prevTitle;
    };
  }, []);
}

function MyComponent(): JSX.Element => {
  useTitle('Title while MyComponent is mounted');

  return <div>My Component</div>;
}
```

This is a pretty straight forward solution, `useTitle` sets the document title and when the component unmounts it's reset to whatever it was previously.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. But, it sure would be nice not to have to. The concept is reusable enough to just be on npm.

Comment: title should be in the useEffect dependency array

Answer (score 19):

If you are wondering, you can set it directly inside the render function:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        document.title = 'wow'
        return <p>Hello</p>
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

For function component:

```js
function App() {
    document.title = 'wow'
    return <p>Hello</p>
}
```

But, this is a **bad practice** because [it will block the rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72319662/9157799) (React prioritize the rendering first).

#### The good practice:

Class component:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    // you can also use componentDidUpdate() if the title is not static
    componentDidMount(){
        document.title = "good"
    }

    render() {
        return <p>Hello</p>
    }
}
```

Function component:

```js
function App() {
    // for static title, pass an empty array as the second argument
    // for dynamic title, put the dynamic values inside the array
    // see: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects
    useEffect(() => {
        document.title = 'good'
    }, []);

    return <p>Hello</p>
}
```

Comment: This is a typical error that appears in many react code bases: DON'T DO THAT ! Every render methods should be pure functions (no side effects), if you need to perform a side effect: useEffect for functional components, or component events in classes (more info: https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/8avfej/what_does_side_effects_mean_in_react/dx1xo1l)

Comment: +1 to Elias' comment. Even if you have the right way listed, this answer might cause people to put it in the `render` func.

Answer (score 16):

you should set document title in the life cycle of 'componentWillMount':

```
componentWillMount() {
    document.title = 'your title name'
  },
```

update for hooks:

```
useEffect(() => {
    document.title = 'current Page Title';
  }, []);
```

Comment: componentWillMount() is deprecated in latest react version 16

Comment: In this case, as in most of time cases, when you have to remove deprecated componentWillMount, move your code to componentDidMount

Answer (score 15):

React [Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) can let you render to elements outside the root React node (such at `<title>`), as if they were actual React nodes. So now you can set the title cleanly and without any additional dependencies:

Here's an example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Title extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.titleEl = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0];
    }

    render() {
        let fullTitle;
        if(this.props.pageTitle) {
            fullTitle = this.props.pageTitle + " - " + this.props.siteTitle;
        } else {
            fullTitle = this.props.siteTitle;
        }

        return ReactDOM.createPortal(
            fullTitle || "",
            this.titleEl
        );
    }
}
Title.defaultProps = {
    pageTitle: null,
    siteTitle: "Your Site Name Here",
};

export default Title;
```

Just put the component in the page and set `pageTitle`:

```
<Title pageTitle="Dashboard" />
<Title pageTitle={item.name} />
```

Comment: Wow, looks so promising, React Helmet and document.title both work, but this is awesome :) Thanks

Comment: I loved this solution until I realized that it merely appends `fullTitle` to the content already  found in index.html's `<title>Default Title</title>`.

Comment: Just remove default title in your module (not in `constructor`!)

```

import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const titleNode = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0];
titleNode.innerText = '';

export default class Title extends React.PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node,
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.el = titleNode;
  }
  render() {
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(
        this.props.children,
        this.el,
    );
  }
}

```

Answer (score 14):

Helmet is really a great way of doing it, but for apps that only need to change the title, this is what I use:
(modern way React solution - using Hooks)

1. Create change page title component

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const ChangePageTitle = ({ pageTitle }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const prevTitle = document.title;
    document.title = pageTitle;
    return () => {
      document.title = prevTitle;
    };
  });

  return <></>;
};

export default ChangePageTitle;
```

2. Use the component

```
import ChangePageTitle from "../{yourLocation}/ChangePageTitle";

...

return (
    <>
      <ChangePageTitle pageTitle="theTitleYouWant" />
      ...
    </>
  );

...
```

Answer (score 11):

For React v18+, custom hooks will be the simplest approach.

**Step 1:** Create a hook. (hooks/useDocumentTitle.js)

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
export const useDocumentTitle = (title) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        document.title = `${title} - WebsiteName`;
    }, [title]);

    return null;
}
```

**Step 2:** Call the hook on every page with a custom title according to that page. (pages/HomePage.js)

```
import { useDocumentTitle } from "../hooks/useDocumentTitle";

const HomePage = () => {
    useDocumentTitle("Website Title For Home Page");
    
    return (
        <>           
            <main>
                <section>Example Text</section>
            </main>            
        </>
    );
}

export { HomePage };
```

Works well for dynamic pages as well, just pass the product title or whatever content you want to display.

Answer (score 10):

You have multiple options for this problem I would highly recommend to either use `React Helmet` or create a hook using `useEffect`. Instead of writing your own hook, you could also use the one from `react-use`:

#### [React Helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';

const MyComponent => () => (
  <Helmet>
    <title>My Title</title>
  </Helmet>
)
```

#### [react-use](https://github.com/streamich/react-use)

```
import React from 'react';
import { useTitle } from 'react-use';

const MyComponent = () => {
  useTitle('My Title');

  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Simply you can create a function in a js file and export it for usages in components

like below:

```
export default function setTitle(title) {
  if (typeof title !== "string") {
     throw new Error("Title should be an string");
  }
  document.title = title;
}
```

and use it in any component like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import setTitle from './setTitle.js' // no need to js extension at the end

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    setTitle("i am a new title");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        see the title
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following below with `document.title = 'Home Page'`

```
import React from 'react'
import { Component } from 'react-dom'


class App extends Component{
  componentDidMount(){
    document.title = "Home Page"
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <p> Title is now equal to Home Page </p>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

or You can use this npm package `npm i react-document-title`

```
import React from 'react'
import { Component } from 'react-dom'
import DocumentTitle from 'react-document-title';


class App extends Component{


  render(){
    return(
      <DocumentTitle title='Home'>
        <h1>Home, sweet home.</h1>
      </DocumentTitle>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this too thoroughly, but this seems to work. Written in TypeScript.

```
interface Props {
    children: string|number|Array<string|number>,
}

export default class DocumentTitle extends React.Component<Props> {

    private oldTitle: string = document.title;

    componentWillUnmount(): void {
        document.title = this.oldTitle;
    }

    render() {
        document.title = Array.isArray(this.props.children) ? this.props.children.join('') : this.props.children;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
export default class App extends React.Component<Props, State> {

    render() {
        return <>
            <DocumentTitle>{this.state.files.length} Gallery</DocumentTitle>
            <Container>
                Lorem ipsum
            </Container>
        </>
    }
}
```

Not sure why others are keen on putting their entire app *inside* their `<Title>` component, that seems weird to me.

By updating the `document.title` inside `render()` it'll refresh/stay up to date if you want a dynamic title. It should revert the title when unmounted too. Portals are cute, but seem unnecessary; we don't really need to manipulate any DOM nodes here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ReactDOM and altering `<title>` tag

```
ReactDOM.render(
   "New Title",
   document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0]
);
```

Comment: -1 because a separate `ReactDOM.render` cannot interact with any existing state. So this approach have no benefit over `document.title = ...`, unless you only use React to maintain title, which is ... very unusual. In a normal react app, something like `React.createPortal` is needed. Or just simply set `document.title`.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to use react-document-configuration

`npm install react-document-configuration --save`

**Example:**

````
import React from "react";
import Head from "react-document-configuration";

export default function Application() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Head title="HOME" icon="link_of_icon" />
            <div>
                <h4>Hello Developers!</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};```
````

Answer (score 0):

you can create TabTittleHelper.js and

```
export const TabTittle = (newTitle) => {
document.title=newTitle;
return document.title;
};
```

later you writed all screens

```
TabTittle('tittleName');
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is a good practice or not, but In index.js headers I put:

```
document.title="Page Title";
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a simple hook:

```
export default function usePageTitle(title: string) {
    document.title = `${title} - effOne Hub`;
}
```

That I then call from each page renderer

```
export default function About() {
    usePageTitle('About');

    ...

    return <>Page Content</>
}
```

Comment: You don't cleanup the title and "set it back" when component is cleared, not a hook per-se :)

Answer (score -1):

```
const [name, setName] = useState("Jan");
  useEffect(() => 
    {document.title =   "Celebrate " +  {name}.name  ;}
  );
```

Comment: It is easier to accept an answer like this if you explain your code example and put it into the context of the question.

Comment: `useEffect`  was also suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56385973/3744182) by [Jordan Daniels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9009196/jordan-daniels) among others.  Might you please [edit] your answer to explain a little how your answer differs from theirs?

Answer (score -9):

If you're a beginner you can just save yourself from all that by going to the public folder of your react project folder and edit the title in "index.html" and put yours. Don't forget to save so it will reflect.