# In reactjs how to change the Page title as same as the page route link name?

Tags: reactjs

In Reactjs, How to change the page title as dynamically. For Example: When we redirect to a new page that new page route line should come as a page title

For Example: If Home page then tile should be xxx Home, if in contact page then title should be xxx Contact

Comment: Do you mean document title?

Comment: You can use some npm package to handle that for you. Here is simple one [react-document-title](https://github.com/gaearon/react-document-title) or you can use [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) which has lot more features.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you set the document title in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46160461/how-do-you-set-the-document-title-in-react)

Comment: @SaniaKhushbakhtJamil yes

Comment: @VaibhavVishal i have tried the both,,,but its not taking the value from the link whateven i ahve to give manualy

Comment: @VaibhavVishal react-document-title working well. but i have to give the Tile for each page  manually instead of that is it possible to get it automatically from the page link name for example:  <Link to="/my_bookings/services" className={window.location.pathname.includes('my_bookings') ? styles.activeNavBar : ''}>
                  My Bookings
                </Link> for this i need page title like My Bookings

Comment: I don't think that it can be automatic, when the component for route `/my_bookings/services` mounts after you click the link, it doesn't knows which link was clicked to get there. You can have multiple links pointing to same route but with different text in different places of your app. Also what if the user enters the route `example.com/my_bookings/services` directly in the url bar instead of visiting `example.com` first then clicking your link, what will you do then. What you should do is wrap your routes(`<Route path=.... />`) with `<DocumentTitle />` like this:

Comment: `<Route path="/my_bookings/services" render={() => <DocumentTitle title='My Bookings'>
      <MyComponent />
    </DocumentTitle>} />`

Answer (score 4):

You can use Hooks, and on changing state you can use its `useEffect()` method.

For example,

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Example = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  // Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:
  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the document title using the browser API
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Picked from [React Hooks documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 import React from 'react'
 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'


 class TestPage extends React.Component{
   componentDidMount(){
    document.title = "Test page title"
   }

    render(){
     return(
      <p> hello world! </p>
     );
    }
  }

  ReactDOM.render(
    <TestPage/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

Comment: thanks...this one is working but i dont want like this. ihave 250+ pages. So its not possible to go each and every page and giving title. That's why i asked to give the link name as a page title. hope you understand my need!!