# Dynamic page title with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic, title

I want to make a Dynamic page title on ReactJS. I try a lot of things , but didn't succeed. I make an array with data:

```
let pageTitles = [
    {key:"/Home", title:"Welcome Home"},
    {key:"/SecondPage", title:"Shop"},
    {key:"/ThirdPage", title:"ContactUs"},
];
```

In html is only `<title></title>` , I use `let pathname = window.location.pathname;` If it return "/Home" or "/ThirdPage" to set a new title dynamically. 
I've tried something like that:

```
for (var i = 0, len = pageTitles.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (pageTitles[i].key === pathname) {
            var hhh = pageTitles[i].text;
        }
    }
document.title = hhh
```

But obviously didn't work. I'm sorry if there is a topic like that, but I didn't found it.I have a restriction to install modules.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46160461/how-do-you-set-the-document-title-in-react) might help

Comment: I forgot to write that I have a restriction to install modules. Sorry

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you set the document title in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46160461/how-do-you-set-the-document-title-in-react)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you need to avoid installing modules, you could do this as helper file, then just import it in module you need and call in `componentDidMount`

```
export function seo(data = {}) {
  data.title = data.title || 'Default title';
  data.metaDescription = data.metaDescription || 'Default description';

  document.title = data.title;
  document.querySelector('meta[name="description"]').setAttribute('content', data.metaDescription);
}
```

```
import React from 'react';
import {seo} from '../helpers/seo';

export default class SomeClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    seo({
      title: 'This is my title only shown on this page',
      metaDescription: 'With some meta description'
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <h1>Hello World</h1>;
  }
}
```

You could also just call directly `document.title = 'My new title'` anywhere, but if you extract it as function you have the option to have default one and just provide override when you want to.

Edit: upon inspecting your code, if you change `hhh = pageTitles[i].text;` to `hhh = pageTitles[i].title;` it will work. Would be nice to declare the `var` outside of the loop. Also would be nice to have default value.