# How can I set state when calling component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm very new to react, and got a bit stuck already. I've made a component for an Article Topper that's repeated many times across the site. It has a logo, a title, and a few share buttons and just sits above the article with the name of the article.

What I want to do is update the title name when I call the component, as each article will have a different name.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      topper: []
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="articletopper">
        <div className="left-cell">
          <p>
            <img
              className="logo"
              alt=""
              src={require("../images/logo.png")}
            />
            {this.state.topper}
          </p>
        </div> ...
```

Then in the actual page I want to call this and update the topper state.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Team">
        <Articletopper>Title of Article?</Articletopper>
      </div> 
    );
  }
}
```

I am aware you are not supposed to update state when you call a component, just wondered if there was a way. The purpose of this is just to make the code cleaner when creating a new article.

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: Thanks for the responses, sorry if I wasn't clear. I want to update the title of the article without pasting tons of html each time. I think I need to use props based on what other people have said. For example I want to do:

```
<ArticleTopper> Article 1 Title </ArticleTopper>
<p> Article1... </p>
<ArticleTopper> Article 2 Title </ArticleTopper>
<p> Article2... </p>
```

and so on...

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are trying to do. Could you explain it better? Maybe with more code and examples...

Comment: Would using a prop work instead: <Articletopper title="Title of Article"><Articletopper>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you set the document title in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46160461/how-do-you-set-the-document-title-in-react)

Comment: If I understand your question properly, you have a component and that is being called in many places. But you want some part of the component to be customizable. You could use `props` for this purpose

Comment: Oups, I think I misread at first the title of the page, not a header component. Anyway, here's another way: [use the `children` prop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49706823/1218980).

Comment: You don't need `state` for this at all. As was already pointed out, you can simply pass a prop: `<ArticleTopper title="The Title" />` then add `{this.props.title}` to your JSX.

Comment: Which react version are you using?

Comment: Hi thanks for the replies, updated post with a bit more clarity. I think Props is what I need.

Comment: I'm using version "react": "^16.12.0", if that helps. Still having trouble working this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the state by props while constructing.

If the `title` you give the component can vary over time，you may need to ask lifecycle method `componentDidUpdate` for help.

Answer (score 0):

So I was just overcomplicating the whole thing.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="articletopper">
        <div className="left-cell">
          <p>
            <img
              className="dragonball"
              alt=""
              src={require("../images/dragonball.png")}
            />
            {this.props.title}
          </p>
        </div>
```

Just needed `this.props.title` where I wanted the Article Title to be. And then...

```
import Articletopper from "../articletopper/articletopper";

class Team extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Team">
        <Articletopper title={"Hello"}></Articletopper>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Team;
```

As I said, still very new to this and I overthought what I wanted to do! Didn't need state, just props!