# React: why set the document title inside useEffect?

Tags: reactjs

I just watched [a talk from React Conf 2018](https://youtu.be/dpw9EHDh2bM?t=2225). In the video, the speaker shows 2 ways to set the document title. The first is by using the Lifecycle methods (`componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`) if we use a class component, the second one is by using the `useEffect` hook if we use a function component. It looks like that's the recommended way to do it according to answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46160461/9157799).

But, I tested the following code and it seems to work just fine to set the document title directly:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function App() {
    document.title = 'wow'
    return <p>Hello</p>
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

The title changed:
[image: screenshot]

Is there any significance of setting the document title inside `useEffect` or `componentDidMount`?
Or is it because [it was the only way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46160461/9157799) to set the document title?
Is it okay to set the document title directly like I did in the snippet above?

**Update:**

It also works with class component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        document.title = 'wow'
        return <p>Hello</p>
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: While I don't feel like this is the best question for Stack Overflow. I have also asked the same question... It works in the render, why do I need the useEffect? I haven't found a great explanation for this anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, the `render` function in React, is considered to be a `pure` function.

A `pure` function should not have any side-effects. Eventually updating the `document.title` means that you are referencing the `document` directly from `render`-> which is already considered a side effect.

`Render` should mainly do one thing -> `render` some JSX, if there is a need to do some API calls/interact with the `document`/`window` etc..., this should be placed in `componentDidMount/componentDidUpate` for a class Component, OR in a `useEffect/useLayoutEfect` for a functional component based on hooks.

(`useEffect` for e.g. is a function that runs asynchronously, and updating the document title from it will not block the rendering, whereas doing it directly will block it.)

Answer (score 2):

Use [react-helment](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) which is also widely used in other frameworks with the same name as helmet express ...

Here is the same code:

```
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";

class Application extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
        <div className="application">
            <Helmet>
                <meta charSet="utf-8" />
                <title>My Title</title>
                <link rel="canonical" href="http://example.org/example" />
            </Helmet>
            ...
        </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Another way to use via props to  which is cleaner IMO

```
...
<Helmet titleTemplate={`%s | ${props.title}`} defaultTitle={constants.defaultTitle} />
```

You may also use [react-helmet-async](https://github.com/staylor/react-helmet-async) for more features.